# Yammer API - How to make user group admin

Tags: yammer

Please let me know, if any Inputs on how to make a Yammer Group Admin, or add user as group admin.

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is an api endpoint which is not in the documentation bu being used by the Yammer App itself.
User must be in the group before, it will not add the user itself.

Make Admin:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups/{groupId}/make_admin?user_id={userId}
```

Revoke Admin:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups/{groupId}/revoke_admin?user_id={userId}
```

Hope this is still helpfull, since the posting date is really old.

Comment: Yes sir! That works!! Thank you. However, please note that this will only work with the POST method. For example: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups/{GROUP_ID}/make_admin?user_id={USER_ID}